# Highlight text word by word in a sentence on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Here is the code that I have tried so far but its not working

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="highlight('fox')">Highlight</button>
<div id="inputText">The fox went over the fence</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight
{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
function highlight(text)
{
inputText = document.getElementById("inputText")
var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML
var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
if ( index >= 0 )
{ 
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML 
}

}
```

Comment: It works. You are not using the fiddle correctly. Check this ***[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/3/)***

Comment: currently its highlighting only 'fox' in a sentence but i want to highlight every word in a sentence one by one when i click the button but not able to achieve it. please help

Comment: You tagged the question `jQuery` maybe  you can start using jQuery? :)

Comment: i am not getting how to achieve it by jquery :-|

Comment: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/10/

Comment: its the same not highlighting each word of sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with :)

http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/11/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('.highlightButton').on('click', function (text) {
        $inputText = $('#inputText');

        words = $inputText.text().match(/\w+/g);
        if (i >= words.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        words.splice(i, 0, "<span class='highlight'>");
        words.splice(i + 2, 0, "</span>");
        $inputText.html(words.join(' '));
        i += 1;
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** Automatic word switching :)

http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/15/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i,
    timerId,
    speed = 100, //speed in ms
    higlightWord = function (text, index) {
        var words = text.match(/\w+/g);
        if (index >= words.length) {
            return text;
        }
        words.splice(index, 0, "<span class='highlight'>");
        words.splice(index + 2, 0, "</span>");
        return words.join(' ');
    };
    $('.highlightButton').bind('click', function () {
        $inputText = $('#inputText');
        i = 0;
        if (timerId) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
        timerId = setInterval(function () {
            var sentence = higlightWord($inputText.text(), i);

            if (sentence !== $inputText.text()) {
                i += 1;
            } else {
                clearInterval(timerId);
            }
            $inputText.html(sentence);
        }, speed);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you :) its working fine on fiddle, can you tell me what version of jquery i need to call in script tag as its not working on my system...

Comment: and is it possible that it moves automatically from word to word ie: we click only once and it highlight complete sentence word by word ??

Comment: yes it's possible with a timeout :) I'll update in a sec :) and it seems like 1.7 and up should do ;)

Comment: for older versions replace `.on` with `.bind`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It could probably be cleaned up a bit though.
http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/9/

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){highlight('fox')});
function highlight(text)
{
    console.log($('#inputText').text());
    //inputText = document.getElementById("inputText")
    var innerHTML = $('#inputText').text();
    var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
    if ( index >= 0 )
    { 
        innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        $('#inputText').html(innerHTML);  
    }

}
```

Comment: woops, forgot to remove the log.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly works, you're just not using jsfiddle the right way.

no need to add

```
<script>
```

tags around css and js. Also on the left side you'll need to set the js "No wrap - in

http://jsfiddle.net/F5NUd/8/

Comment: i want that when i click on button all the words get highlight in a sequential way ie: for example if this is a sentence "stackoverflow is the best website" then if i will click on button then firstly 'stackoverflow' will highlight for certain time duration then 'is' then 'best' then 'website'.

Comment: wow, that's a whole new quetsion. you need to update your question for it. Also, here in SO we encourage people to try it for themselves first, we are here to guide you through a specific problem but not the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this, http://codepen.io/sumitguptainfo/pen/nuFGa

```
 <script>
function highlight(text)
{
    inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
    var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML
    var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
    if ( index >= 0 )
    { 
        innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight' id='hightText'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        Highlightedtext = document.getElementById("hightText");
        Highlightedtext.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }

}
</script>
```